# Como transformar o JSON_ENCODE do PHP para JSON em javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Olá,

Meu javascript puxa o resultado de um select feito no PHP, o que chega no Javascript é o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não entendo por que esta vindo com esse "string()" na frente,

já tentei usar JSON.parse, mas não funciona, como na imagem abaixo,

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A pergunta é: Como eu transformo essa string em JSON?

Comment: Bem-vindo Sydrack Santos, para obter boas respostas esse post vai lhe ajudar: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485

Comment: Podes mostrar o código no PHP que gera essa string e como estás a receber no JavaScript? sem ver o código é dificil ajudar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você provavelmente esta fazendo isso no seu código de PHP:

```
var_dump($variavel);
```

O que você precisa fazer é:

```
echo $variavel;
```

Answer (score 0):

**No contexto do seu php**

```
$suaVariavel = json_encode($seu_Obj_ou_Arr);
print($suaVariavel);
```

**No contexto do Javascript**

```
$.getJSON(url.php, parans, function(respJson){
   // Aqui você acessa seu json já no formato de objeto.
   // Coloca isso --- respJson.nome --- em qualquer lugar que desejar.
   // E assim por diante.
});
```

PS: Não esquece de char o jQuery.js na sua página para funcionar o getJSON